# Prometheus Alerting when Kubernetes service are down

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have few services in my Kubernetes cluster. I need to get alert when any of the service is down.

Right now, I'm getting alerts for other scenarios like pod not *ready*, *Crashloopbackoff* etc.

I'm using official helm chart kube-prometheus-stack. Is there any expression available to get service status?

Looking for some insights or help on this

I tried *Blackbox-exporter* too, but I was able to get alert when I add external domain. But my requirement is to get alerts when services are down.